# Why is the Metacognitive Processor in Caprica needed?

Tags: plot-explanation, caprica

In [Caprica](http://en.battlestarwiki.org/wiki/Portal%3aCaprica), the spin-off series from [Battlestar Galactica](http://en.battlestarwiki.org/wiki/Portal%3aBattlestar_Galactica_%28RDM%29), a central plot point is the [Metacognitive Processor](http://en.battlestarwiki.org/wiki/Meta-cognitive_processor) (MCP). It's seemingly required to get the virtual Zoe in to a robot.

However, the virtual Zoe is already fully functional in v-world, which runs on standard computing hardware, without an MCP.

So why is the MCP required to get Zoe in to a Cylon robot?

Comment: If one was to randomly speculate, perhaps the MCP packs a lot of punch for the size?  It could be that the v-world mainframe storing her is huge and you couldn't shove enough standard processing power into a human size body along with all the mechanical stuff?

Answer (score 2):

You are asking two different questions:

> Why is the meta-cognitive processor needed?

The processor is needed to connect and convert a virtual consciousness to the mechanics of a real robot. To quote from [your own link](http://en.battlestarwiki.org/wiki/Meta-cognitive_processor), the MCP is *intended to bring higher brain function to cybernetic life forms*.

Just like actual persons need virtual reality glasses in order to be able to connect with a virtual reality, the robot needs something to connect with a decision making or controlling consciousness too. But a robot does not have a human brain, so it needs something more advanced than just the glasses, it needs the meta-cognitive processor.

> Why is the MCP required to get Zoe into a Cylon robot?

You mean why the MCP from the Vergis Corporation? Because it is more advanced and possibly more capacitive as the one from Graystone Industries. The beginning of the movie shows a Graystone robot not performing very well. It might not be possible to upload Zoe's complete virtual consciousness to it.